Change between two floats at a constant speed
Need to know if there is a more practical way to do this. I need to change between two angles at a constant speed. The angles are for instance 5f start and -50f end
a lerp is useless because it works on constant time not constant speed from every time I asked Google for help on lerp.
lerpangle worked more as a slerp than a lerp and was not constant speed
When I want to move between two places at a constant speed I can use vector2.movetowards but I can't do a float.movetowards so I have kind of faked it by doing this
theAngle = (Vector2.MoveTowards(new Vector2(theAngle,0),new Vector2(EndAngle,0), lerpSpeed * Time.deltaTime)).x;

now i know there HAS to be an easier way to do this. Sometimes the angle goes from positive to negative sometimes negative to positive. sometimes positive to positive up or down. Etc. The math is there but I seem to be pulling a blank on this one.
I have asked Google to show me a lerp at constant speed, but it keeps giving me a lerp at constant time. This is what it gives. I don't know how many different ways I tried to word it, but it keeps coming back to this.
float tween = t / lerpSpeed; 
float angle = Mathf.Lerp(animateFrom, animateTo, tween); 
t += Time.DeltaTime;

I know there is a way to do it I here asking for help on what that way is.

I'm confused by your comment on lerp, it works by you providing a start and end value and smoothly, linearly (constant speed), transitioning between them with a value from 0 to 1. How is this not what you want?

lerp if fed the right data is exactly how to do it.....

You are looking for Mathf.MoveTowards

LERP is just that: "linear". You're dealing with "rotation"; which is linear for a given duration. If my "angular" velocity is known; and my diameter can be calculated; the duraction required to rotate a given amount can also be determined. And vise versa: the angle represents a portion of the circumference (distance); the duration determined by how fast you want to travel that distance.

we are not dealing with rotation. we are dealing with 1 float changing to another float.
The lerp probably would work but i cant figure it out. This is what i had for the lerp
float tween = t / lerpSpeed;
float angle = Mathf.Lerp(animateFrom, animateTo, tween);
t += Time.DeltaTime

I know if fed the right data it would work. thats why im here on this place asking for help.... what is the right data?


When I want to move between two places at a constant speed I can use vector2.movetowards but I can't do a float.movetowards

Yes, of course you can! Well almost ;)
I would be Mathf.MoveTowards
theAngle = Mathf.MoveTowards(theAngle, EndAngle, lerpSpeed * Time.deltaTime);


dude. thanks. i knew there had to be something simple. The amount of things hidden in Mathf. Wow. thanks

If you just want to change a float value by constant speed, you can try this.
Such as, you need the float value decrease 10 in 1 sec.
float lerpSpeed = 10f;
float tween = 0f;
float startValue = 5f;
float endValue = -50f;
void Updata(){
    //decrease in this frame
    float degree = Time.deltaTime * lerpSpeed;
    //calculate the decrease ratio
    tween += Math.Abs(degree / (endValue - startValue));

    float angle = Math.Lerp(startValue, endValue, tween);
}


that kind of sounds like constant time rather than constant rate. If it changes by 10 in 1 sec would is take 2 secs for 20 or is it constant time so that it takes 1 second for any change? Someone above posted Mathf. Movetowards which i think i will use since it is easier to use than lerping. Thanks for the comment. I might try it out to see if it answers my question but will still go with the movetowards.
